# Does webpack evaluate and remove unreachable code inside a function?

Tags: webpack

I have a function like this

```
function webpackTest(){
  if(1==0)
  {
    console.log("MyConsoleLog");
  }
}

function doThings() {
   // Before test things
   webpackTest()
   // After test things
}
```

It seems like that my build output does not even include the string "MyConsoleLog" anywhere

My question is that does/can webpack evaluate code and remove "dead code", even intentionally **inside a function**

And if there is away to disable that, specifically

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The built code removal was the work of Terser webpack plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin

If you face the same situation that I faced, check the Webpack plugin configuration, the section for Terser. The config section that govern code removal is `compression` such as `conditionals`, `dead_code`, `evaluate`
https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options